# Use Different VPN for Each Windows User Account?

Tags: windows, vpn, user-accounts

I've recently installed tunnelbear.com VPN on a remote server with several windows user accounts. I noticed that when I enable tunnel bear on one user account, disconnect (without logging out) and sign into a different user account all data is sent through the same VPN. In other words, the VPN has a system-wide effect.

How can I create a different VPN connection for each of the several logon sessions I have running simultaneously on my Windows Server computer? My question is not specifically about tunnel bear, I'm just using this as an example of VPN. This happens no matter how I enable VPN on a single user account.

I happen to be using amazon web services (windows server) but I don't think this effects the outcome.

**Clarification:**

My reason for this question is as follows: Each user account represents a different client. For each client, I am connecting to an external SOAP API and making certain requests on behalf of client. Requests on behalf of each client must come from a unique IP. I thought that the best way to accomplish this (aside for setting up an entirely new VPS/server for each client) is to have each user account run a different VPN which means that all requests from a given user account will automatically be sent through a unique / specific IP.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Didn't realize that. Thanks. I've edited the question. I hope it now  shinny and clean :)

Comment: Much better. Up voted accordingly.